# Как отрендерить данные с API?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

На странице, есть два запроса на бэк. 1 - все товары, 2 - конкретный товар(его id).
Проблема состоит в том, что у меня не выводится конкретный продукт на странице. В консоле отправляет 400 ошибку, т.к. url = undefiend.

```
function ItemPage({ id }) {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([])
    const [productList, setProductList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const responseId = await getProduct(id)

          setProduct(responseId.data)
          console.log(responseId.data)
        };
    
        fetchData();
    }, [id]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const responseList = await getProducts();

          setProductList(responseList.data.data)
        };
    
        fetchData();
    }, []);


<div className="content-inner in-col">
                <div className="item-page">
                    <div className="item-page__holder">
                        <img className="item-page__image" src={ product.image } alt="item" />
                        <Button 
                            label="Purchase"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="item-page__content">
                        <h3>{ product.label }</h3>
                        <h3>{ product.price }</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h3 className="title medium-height-padding">More products</h3>
                <div className="list__item">
                    {
                        productList && productList.map(item => 
                            <ProductItem ......

export function getProduct(id) {
    return axios.get(URL + `products/${id}`);
}

export function getProducts() {
    return axios.get(URL + 'products');
}
```

Comment: а что такое `URL`? Где его инициализация?

Comment: ну url = http:/localhost:8000/.